# JMeter - Read Files from Directory

Tags: jmeter

Using Apache JMeter

First question: I was able to read **one single file** (containing all the data) from a directory and use its data.

However now the requirement is to have **a separate**  file for each data point, that means I will have to put **many** data files in a directory and then read the files off that directory. I have a set of data files, but I do not know how to read each of the files in a loop and send it to JMeter.

Second Question: the data we are talking about here is a JSON msg, and it's indented and **multi-line**, how to read a multi-line file into a **single input variable**? Again, I had no problem when the JSON msg is a single line.

Answer (score 22):

1. Use [Beanshell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler) to convert files list into a JMeter Variable:

   - Add a [Beanshell Sampler](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) to your test plan
   - Put the following code into the Sampler's "Script" area:

     ```
     File folder = new File("/path/to/your/folder");
     File[] files = folder.listFiles();
     int counter = 1;
     for (File file : files) {
         vars.put("file_" + counter, file.getAbsolutePath());
         counter++;
     }
     ```

     It will result into variables set like:

     file_1=/path/to/your/folder/file1.txt
     file_2=/path/to/your/folder/file2.txt
     etc.
2. Add [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) **after** Beanshell Sampler and configure it as follows:

   - Input variable prefix: `file`
   - Start index for loop: `0`
   - End index for loop: leave blank
   - Output variable name: anything meaningful, i.e. `current_file`
   - Check `Add "_" before number`
3. Put your main sampler as a child of the ForEach Controller. Where required address each file contents using [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function as `${__FileToString(${current_file},,)}`

Comment: This worked for me. Make sure you use Bean Shell Sampler and not Bean Shell PreProcessor.

Comment: Hi Dimitri, is it possible to not store each file path in variable and with each file perform an HTTP request?

Comment: In 2020 there is [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter/) plugin which generates a single variable and reads the next file into it for each thread/iteration. Directory Listing Config can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Answer (score 0):

If using the directory listing data source, in order to loop through you should use the where you would use `$current_file`. `__FileToString()` function as `${__FileToString(${current_file},,)}` mentioned above by *Dmitri T* and *alexandrul*.

Very simple to over look.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to read file data

```
FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter("D:\\report\\Results.csv",true);
BufferedWriter buff = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
    
buff.write("file created \n");

buff.close();
fWriter.close();
```