# jmeter: Avoid duplicate execution in ForEach Controller

Tags: jmeter

I have a folder with many JSON-Files and I would like to send them parallel to a Webservice using jmeter.

I already used a BeanShell Sampler to collect the files into jmeter-variables. Then I used a ForEach Controller to perform the HTTP Request ([see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32360501/3938448)).

But the problem is, when using a thread count > 1, the json-files are processed multiple times. Each thread loops through the list of JSON-files for its own.

Do you know how multiple threads can share the output variable of a ForEach Controller?

See **jmeter configuration**

[image: jmeter configuration]. There are 3 (threads) * 2 (files) = 6 debug outputs. But I would like that e.g. thread 1 processes first.json, thread 3 processes second.json and thread 2 does not have any left. So no file is processed multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of implementing your requirement is using [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) plugin.

The plugin reads all the files from the folder provided into a **single** JMeter variable:

[image]

As you can see in the above setup 3rd user doesn't execute the sampler as the folder contains only 2 files and both have been processed already:

[image]

You can install Directory Listing Config plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!